# EF Core - constant value for all columns with a specific name

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Are you aware of an elegant way in EF Core of inserting a constant value for all the column of all the table with name `ColumnNameABC`?

What I mean is that regardless of the data a user tries to insert / update, if the column name is `ColumnNameABC`, the value is always a constant text of `CONST123`.

Of course I could overwrite the GET method in all the entities classes, but that would require a lot of work and maintenance.

If you are aware of an elegant solution that would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done for all entities in the last step before applying the changes to the database and that is `SaveChanges` method.

For this purpose you have to have a base model which contains this property `ColumnNameABC`.

So let's assume this is your base model:

```cs
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColumnNameABC { get; set; }
    //can be other properties as well like CreatedAt
}

public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColumnNameABC { get; set; }
}
```

And this is your database model

```cs
public class Foo : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, you can override the `SaveChanges` method in the db context like:

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entiry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entiry.Entity is IBaseEntity model)
            {
                model.CodemnNameABC= "CONST123";
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Just be sure that there are several `SaveChanges()` methods like
`SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)` or `SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)`, so based on the logic and usage, you need to override them.

Comment: should I then override SaveChangesAsync and others?

Comment: @EmilioPetrangeli it depends on your logic, if your using SaveChangesAsync in your repositories, yes you need to override it as well